# Esperar a que un video cargue antes de reproducirlo

Tags: javascript, html, rendimiento, networking

Una vez los usuarios pulsan el un botón se reproduce un vídeo que solo pueden ver una vez, sin controles para avanzar, retroceder o pausar y una vez ha llegado al final hago un redirect a otro lado por lo que es imposible volver a verlo. Esto debe seguir siendo así, el problema es que en dispositivos móviles el vídeo se reproduce y se corta hasta que carga un fragmento y así repetidas veces hasta finalizar. Es muy necesario que lo puedan ver ininterrumpidamente. ¿Como puedo lograrlo? He probado con el atributo preload="auto" de la etiqueta video pero no parece surgir efecto.

Muchas gracias anticipadas!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es esperara a que termine la descarga del vídeo mediante Javascript y luego dar play.

Se puede hacer de varias formas:

1. En [este](http://dinbror.dk/blog/how-to-preload-entire-html5-video-before-play-solved/) enlace te recomiendo la solución 3 y 4
2. Si decides usar XMLHttpRequest, puedes esperar a que finalice la descarga y luego usar `document.getElementById("myVideo").play()`. Te puede interesar este [recurso](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) para entender como funciona XMLHttpRequest y [este](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/loadend_event) dónde se explica el evento disparado al finalizar la petición
3. En caso que decidas usar fetch [este](https://github.com/AnthumChris/fetch-progress-indicators/blob/master/fetch-basic/supported-browser.js) ejemplo es muy bueno

Espero que te sirva :)